# Display json data from jQuery/Ajax in HTML starting with date

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to build a ajax call from some json data

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "websiteurl.com",
    success: function(data)
    {
        jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
            $("#label").append(document.createTextNode(val.label));
            $("#url").append(document.createTextNode(val.url));
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the jSon

```
{
    "2019-01-29T00:00:00+00:00": [
        {
            "type": "refuse",
            "label": "Refuse",
            "url": "http://www.exampleurl-one.com"
        }
    ],
    "2019-02-05T00:00:00+00:00": [
        {
            "type": "gardenwaste",
            "label": "Garden Waste",
            "url": "http://www.exampleurl-two.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "recycling",
            "subtype": "redbox",
            "label": "Red Box",
            "url": "http://www.exampleurl-three.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "recycling",
            "subtype": "bluebag",
            "label": "Blue Bag",
            "url": "http://www.exampleurl-four.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "recycling",
            "subtype": "yellowbag",
            "label": "Yellow Bag",
            "url": "http://www.exampleurl-five.com"
        }
    ],
    "2019-02-12T00:00:00+00:00": [
        {
            "type": "refuse",
            "label": "Refuse",
            "url": "http://www.exampleurl-six.com""
        }
    ],
    "calendar": {
        "url": "http://www.exampleurl-seven.com",
        "label": "Collection Calendar"
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to get it outputting, because the date will change and I want to show that - but then have the other data following, e.g.

Date: 2019-01-29T00:00:00+00:00 (Formatted which I can do)

Label: Refuse

URL: http://www.exampleurl-one.com

I currently get undefined off the dates which doesn't help

Comment: For starters, your JSON has a syntax error.  Once you correct that, what *specifically* is `undefined` in your code?

Comment: @David - I don't have access to the JSON to correct unfortunately and I THINK it's the data itself e.g. refuse, recycling, red box etc.

Comment: Well, if you can't correct the JSON structure then you're going to have to parse it manually.  The syntax error has nothing to do with the field names, it's just a misplaced quotes.  You should probably bring this to the attention of whoever is producing this data for you.

Comment: Will do thanks @David, any tips on where to start parsing it manually?

Comment: I guess the variety of string manipulation functions would be one place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String  Regular expressions may be useful.  You could also treat the JSON as a structured language and tokenize it.  Any approach would need to account for known errors.  Really the path of least resistance here would be to correctly use a standard data format.  The error here is pretty random, and trying to handle random errors is an endless battle.